# Can every 3D object be properly "described" by three 2D planes ( top, front and right view)?

Tags: technical-drawing

In technical drawing 3D object is "described" with three 2D planes (top, front and right side plane).
Can every 3D object be properly "described" with these  three  2D planes ?

If qube has  complex and unsymmetrical structures on each side , if we  take only front, right side and top view, how we know how looks bottom, left side and back side of that object?

Comment: No not every object can be fully described.  That is why we add section views, breakout views, and many additional views in drawings for such geometries... For simple geometric structures we can often add hidden lines to show any features not directly visible or text as notes.  Some of the simpler items can be fully described with two views.

Comment: @Abel Your comment is a perfectly reasonable answer and should be posted as such.

Comment: I believe a complete answer requires an explanation of this "qube" thing as well...

Comment: Are you forgetting 3D objects can have internal features?

Comment: there are shapes that require more than 3 axes to describe and create, submarine screws being one of them.

Comment: The simplest object can be described as in a single view.  ie. a Sphere, a cube, a rod, piece of sheet metal.

Answer (score 3):

No. Simplest example is the shape formed by the intersection of 3 identical orthogonal cylinders. The resulting shape could be shown in 3 orthogonal views as 3 identical circles, but that could be either a sphere or a Steinmetz solid.

Comment: You'd have to draw the intersection edges, making it circles with X markings across them.  Confusing yes, but not to be confused with a sphere.

Comment: Aye, but it's a good example of an ambiguous drawing. Guess what i did the first day I bought a hole saw?